# Android Fit image to full width using Picasso library

Tags: android

I am using Picasso library to load images and its working fine but after using this library  image is not fit to the layout. If I set image directly to the `ImageView` then image will be fit to the layout .Is there any option to pass method in Picasso to fit image to layout

```
Picasso.with(getContext())
                    .load(R.drawable.dddd).
                    .into(lavdateimageView);
```

Even I tried to call following method but no use

`fit()`,`croptinside()` etc

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="260dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:id="@+id/lavdate_image"
                android:orientation="vertical"

                >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:id="@+id/lavdateimageView" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Text to"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/sss"  />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>



</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally I understood my mistake. I used `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` and now my image is fit to layout

```
  <ImageView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"
      android:id="@+id/myimageView" />
```

Answer (score 17):

I had also same problem so I tried this it works fine

```
Picasso.get()
       .load(IMAGE_URL)
       .fit()
       .centerCrop()
       .into(imageView);
```

Comment: @iCoders try it as it is... means fit and centerCrop at same time it will work perfect

Comment: @Fetal.if i use this then it wont display my image. gues i need to change my xml

Comment: @Fetal.Thanks.I fixed it using android:scaleType="centerCrop"

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the property of your `imageview` like this

```
<ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/lavdateimageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />
```

And then

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(R.drawable.dddd)
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(lavdateimageView)
```

Comment: @shuvro.Thanks i already tired  android:scaleType="centerCrop" and its working fine now.you can see my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

myPicassoProvider.get(activity).load(getImageUrl()).into(image);
```

In this way your image will be as width as you want and will keep aspect ratio